# Cannot access modal-popup.html template in Luma theme

Tags: magento, mamp, magento2

I'm stuck on this point. I don't know why I'm getting this error on a fresh Magento 2 site. I'm using OSX Yosemite 10.10.5 with MAMP.

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /Magento/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Ui/templates/modal/modal-popup.html on this server.

[image: Screenshot of error]

From what I have found this has not been answered elsewhere, so please don't close as unclear or not useful if it can't be answered.

Comment: I'm not sure how much you looked, but this was the first thing that Google gave me: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109201/you-dont-have-permission-to-access-pub-static-frontend-magento-luma-en-us-mage

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Solved Finally!!!!! i am using mac Yosemite 10.10.5 its easy.

step1:

goto root folder of magento like this:

`cd Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Magento`

step2:

and then one by one type these

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

`php bin/magento cache:clean`

and you are done!

if you receive fatal error about Local missing in some php bundle bla bla bla ... in `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` step2. Its because your php is 5.5 or other version than the one running on MAMP. Which you can check by this command

`php -i` its running on mac

and php running on MAMP:
http://localhost:8888/MAMP/index.php?page=phpinfo&language=English

if both are same then you have to find anather solution or make php to the one supported by magento.

if both are not the same you have to change your "mac php" path to "php inside MAMP" folder. todo that: write in terminal

`vim ~/.bash_profile`

new VIM terminal window will be open then type i and past this path or the correct one(in my case its this one):

`export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin:$PATH`

to exit VIM and go back to terminal: esc and then wq or Shift+zz

then in terminal type

`source ~/.bash_profile`

and then come back here to cheers!!!(its important :))

Answer (score -1):

try providing permission for pub and var directory

```
chmod -R 777 var/ pub/
```

if it did not resolve the issue than try deleting static files

```
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/
```

than generate static content again by

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: Still the same problem. and also bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
-bash: bin/magento: No such file or directory

Comment: check out your file stricture 
bin/magento must be there, REF : https://github.com/magento/magento2/

Comment: casas-MBP:~ casa$ /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Magento/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Fatal error: Class 'Locale' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/Locale/Bundle/DataBundle.php on line 64